# rails link_to and button_to with bootstrap button class behaves differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, link-to, button-to

I've following link_to on show article view page,

```
<%= link_to "Add Pictures",
      new_picture_path(article_id: @article.id),
      class: "btn btn-small btn-success" %>
```

This works perfectly by displaying 'link' as a button with the help of "btn" class. Only problem with this is that the text on the button changes to gray after a click (as in visited link visited). How do I keep it as original text color (white in this case)? Or what kinds of css magic do I need to keep the original text color.

Or simply I can fix it by changing it to button_to as follows,

```
<%= button_to "Add Pictures",
      new_picture_path(article_id: @article.id),
      method: :get, class: "btn btn-small btn-success" %>
```

But the problem with this is that, my article_id is get sets to nil, which fails the validation error that article_id is not set.
What do I do? Fix the link_to with css (how?) or fix the button_to issue (how?). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try like this once ..<%= link_to "Add Pictures",
      new_picture_path(article_id: @article.id),
      class: "btn btn-small btn-success", color:inherit %>

Comment: @ Rahul, it fails with "undefined local variable or method `inherit'" error.

Comment: but following two variation works.  <%= link_to "Add Pictures", new_picture_path(article_id: @article.id), class: "btn btn-small btn-success", style: "color:inherit" %>   and  <%= link_to "Add Pictures", new_picture_path(article_id: @article.id), class: "btn btn-small btn-success", style: "color:white" %>

Comment: yes ..you can use it.. i just forgot the syntax

Answer (score 3):

If your css code contains:

```
a:visited {
  color: #666666;
}
```

This may cause a different rendering between `link_to` and `button_to` because `link_to` will be parsed as `<a href=""></a>` and `button_to` will be parsed as `<form>..</form>`.

Note: if you use

```
<%= button_to 'Users', users_path(app_id: application.id), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-info btn-xs' %>
```

Rails will compile as:

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/users?app_id=1">
   <input class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="submit" value="Users">
</form>
```

But the `app_id=1` will not be passed to `params` in rails after you click on the button.

The solutions are :

1. Use `link_to` with class attribute: `style: "color:white"` just like @Rahul says.
2. Remove the css code: `a:visited`